# Why do I receive key release event when key release is not in event mask. (xcb)

Tags: c++, c, xorg, xserver, xcb

I am making a simple xcb application and I noticed that when `XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS` is in the event mask and `XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_RELEASE` is not in the event mask I still get `XCB_KEY_RELEASE` events in my event loop if I hold down a key so that it repeats the key press event. Surely if `XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_RELEASE` is not in the event mask I should never get an `XCB_KEY_RELEASE` event?

Minimum reproducible example:

Run and hold down a key for a few seconds so that the keypress event repeats. This causes the key release event despite `XCB_EVENT__MASK_KEY_RELEASE` not being in the event mask.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

/* notice that the event mask does not conatin XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_RLEASE */
const uint32_t EVENT_MASK
    = XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE
    | XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS;

int main()
{
    int screenNum;
    xcb_connection_t* xcon = xcb_connect(NULL, &screenNum);

    const xcb_setup_t* xsetup = xcb_get_setup(xcon);
    xcb_screen_t* screen;
    {
        xcb_screen_iterator_t iter = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xsetup);
        for (int i = 0; i < screenNum; i++)
            xcb_screen_next(&iter);
        screen = iter.data;
    }
    xcb_window_t window = xcb_generate_id(xcon);
    uint32_t winvals[] = { screen->white_pixel, EVENT_MASK };
    xcb_create_window(
        xcon,
        XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
        window,
        screen->root,
        10, 10,
        150, 150,
        10,
        XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
        screen->root_visual,
        XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK, winvals);
    xcb_map_window(xcon, window);
    xcb_flush(xcon);
    xcb_generic_event_t* event;
    while ((event = xcb_wait_for_event(xcon))) {
        switch (event->response_type & ~0x80) {
        case XCB_EXPOSE: {
            // TODO: draw something
            xcb_flush(xcon);

            break;
        }
        case XCB_KEY_PRESS: {
            xcb_key_press_event_t* kp = (xcb_key_press_event_t*)event;
            printf("key pressed: %u\n", kp->detail);
            break;
        }
        case XCB_KEY_RELEASE: {
            puts("KEY RELEASE EVENT?!");
            break;
        }
        default: {
            printf("unknown event. type = %u\n", event->response_type);
            break;
        }
        }
        free(event);
    }
    xcb_disconnect(xcon);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There must be some fascinating historical backstory to this X server behavior.

Comment: I built and ran your posted code.   I then ran the executable while pressing/releasing several different keys.  There were no XCB_KEY_RELEASE events.  Please clarify exactly what you are doing when the release events occurs.  Note I added the parameter: `-lxcb` to my link step. There were no errors/warnings in compiling nor linking

Comment: @user3629249 Pressing and releasing a key quickly does not cause the key release event. To get the key release event, you must press and hold down a key for a few seconds so that it makes that key repeat. I'm not sure what the proper name for this is but imagine you were going to type "aaaaaaaaaa", you wouldn't press "a" ten times, you would hold down the "a" key because that causes the key down event to repeat. When the key down down event repeats due to holding down the same key is when the key release event occurs. I hope this makes sense.